# Vignetting correction on RGB image with OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, visual-studio, opencv

First of all: I'm new to opencv :-) 
I want to perform a vignetting correction on a 24bit RGB Image. I used an area scan camera as a line camera and put together an image from 1780x2 px parts to get an complete image with 1780x3000 px. Because of the vignetting, i made a white reference picture with 1780x2 px to calculate a LUT (with correction factor in it) for the vignetting removal. Here is my code idea:

```
    Mat white = imread("WHITE_REF_2L.bmp", 0);
    Mat lut(2, 1780, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0));
    lut = 255 / white;
    imwrite("lut_test.bmp", lut*white);
```

As i understood, what the second last line will (hopefully) do, is to divide 255 with every intensity value of every channel and store this in the lut matrice. 
I want to use that lut then to to calculate the “real” (not distorted) intensity
level of each pixel by multiplying every element of the src img with every element of the lut matrice.

obviously its not working how i want to do it, i get a memory exception.

Can anybody help me with that problem?

edit: i'm using opencv 3.1.0 and i solved the problem like this:

```
    // read white reference image
    Mat white = imread("WHITE_REF_2L_D.bmp", IMREAD_COLOR);
    white.convertTo(white, CV_32FC3);
    // calculate LUT with vignetting correction factors
    Mat vLUT(2, 1780, CV_32FC3, Scalar(0.0f));
    divide(240.0f, white, vLUT);
```

of course that's not optimal, i will read in more white references and calculate the mean value to optimize.

[Here's the 2 lines white reference, you can see the shadows at the image borders i want to correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYUje.png)

when i multiply vLUT with the white reference i obviously get a homogenous [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVrjT.png) as the result.

thanks, maybe this can help anyone else ;)

Comment: Please attach the image. It will help others to debug the issue. As you already know, setting opencv and data is already time-taking task. Also, mention opencv version you are using.